# In CSS, pseudo element 'not' on anchor tag is not working

Tags: css

In CSS, I try hard to apply pseudo element having not on the anchor tag of hover and active, but it is not working.

```
a:not(a[name="nobgcolor"]):hover{color:#ffff35;background-color:#ff3355;}
a:not(a[name="nobgcolor"]):active{color:#ffff35;background-color:red;}
```

I have applied background color in hover and active hyperlinks. But I want that background color is not appeared, where property exists as name="nobgcolor". In earlier I want to apply the same on href having top. (To go to Top) But not worked, So I put name= "nobgcolor" at the same place and try the same!!!

```
a:hover:not(a[href*="#top"]){color:#ffff35;background-color:#ff3355;}
a:active:not(a[href*="#top"]){color:#ffff35;background-color:red;}
```

But the codes are not working, they apply on entire page and removes background color. Please guide what I have to do for this situation???

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove a tag from inside as it is targeting the same element

```css
a:hover:not([href*="#top"]) {
  color: #ffff35;
  background-color: #ff3355;
}
a:active:not([href*="#top"]) {
  color: #ffff35;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" name="nobgcolor">test</a>
<br>
<a href="" name="">test1</a>
<br>
<a href="#top" name="nobgcolor">test</a>
<br>
<a href="" name="">test1</a>
```

```css
a:hover:not([name="nobgcolor"]) {
  color: #ffff35;
  background-color: #ff3355;
}

a:active:not([name="nobgcolor"]) {
  color: #ffff35;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" name="nobgcolor">test</a>
<br>
<a href="" name="">test1</a>
<br>
<a href="" name="nobgcolor">test</a>
<br>
<a href="" name="">test1</a>
```